# opencv code speed differences on mac and win7

Tags: windows-7, opencv

I coded from matlab code (localSelfSimilarity) an opencv version. It works perfectly, but speed is on win7 64-bit (amd64 3Ghz 4-core, 8GB ram) much slower than my mac mini (2Ghz core2duo 64-bit, 8GB ram). The speed of same code, same optimzations, same input image on mac, taken with time exec.. is Real 1min, user 57s. On the other hand on win7 (msys) Real is 2min44s, cpu 0.01s, sys..0.015 Cpu is up to 65%. Gprof on win7 shows that 37% of time is used in _mcount_private. As a matter of fact, the matlab-code runs on octave as fast as on the opencv-code. Opencv on mac is older 2.2 and win7 new 2.3.1. Opencv is built with mingw64,
(could that be the problem?) on win7. Yesterday I downloaded Windows SDK 7.1 to use 64-bit cl.exe. The code is compiled ok with nmake, except gpu-part (nvcc throws error about vs configuration, tried the trick to make vcvars64.bat, but that didn't help). I'll try to build the code with vc, and see if there's any difference.
Another code using opencv on win7 runs quite well, only this selfsimilarity is really slow.
Input image is small 200x157 px, using 400x500 px image took 2.5 hrs.

Answer (score 0):

It makes some sense that you are observing better performance with an Intel processor. [OpenCV uses **Intel Integrated Performance Primitives**](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-ipp-with-opencv/) to improve it's performance.

You can compile OpenCV without it and re-run your tests.